How to get name of zip file [php] [ziparchive]
Given a ZipArchive, how is it possible to get the name of the file that is opened?
Let's say I have library function (which I can't edit) and it looks like this
function getZipFile(): ZipArchive
{
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $zip->open("SomeFileNameIDontKnow.zip");
    return $zip;
}

Is there a way to get the filename for me to show a user?
$zip = getZipFile();
print "Opening zip archive " . $zip->functionToGetTheFileName();


Use $zip->filename. From the documentation:
/* Properties */
public readonly int $lastId;
public readonly int $status;
public readonly int $statusSys;
public readonly int $numFiles;
public readonly string $filename;
public readonly string $comment;
...
filename
    File name in the file system

